# Parameter choice rules for L1 regularization?

Tags: sparsity, sparse-model, norm

I am solving an L1 regularized least squares of the form like:

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1} $$

I saw that for the L2 norm case there are several methods to obtain the magnitude of $\lambda$ as seen in the study [Comparing parameter choice methods for regularization of ill-posed problems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378475411000607) .
However, I didn't find anything for the L1 case. What should I be doing besides trial and error to efficiently determine $\lambda$ for this case?

Comment: You can use AIC/BIC or other merit, e.g. adjusted R2, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_model_selection.html

Comment: thank you for the info, i am not sure how to implement this. do I for loop over different values of $\lambda$, then for each iteration calculate the log likelihood by $|A\bf{x}-\bf{y}|^2$ and for number of model parameters count the non-zero elements in $\bf{x}$? also for num of object \ sample size, should I use the distention of $\bf{x}$? I understand that calculating the AIC\BIC given for each $\lambda$  gives me a number and the minimum of the number is the $\lambda$ I should use?

Comment: Yes, you can scan over different values of lamda hyperparameter. LARS Lasso might be also of interest to you. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#least-angle-regression

Comment: but the minimization that is in my question is lasso, so I dont understand.